# Aws Cognito: user can be found by CognitoUserPool, but does not appear in aws management console

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I have the following C# MVC controller action in .NET Core:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> SignUp(SignUpModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = pool.GetUser(model.Email);
            if(user != null)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "User with this email already exists");
                return View(model);
            }

            user.Attributes.Add(CognitoAttribute.Name.AttributeName, model.Email);
            var createdUser = await userManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);

            if(createdUser.Succeeded)
            {
                RedirectToAction("Confirm");
            }
        }
        return View();
    }
```

I am trying to add a user with my email address so that I can test the authorization code functionality.

When I try to register a user with my email address, CognitoUserPool (`pool`) returns a user associated with that email address, so the app tells me that user already exists.

However, when I go to the AWS management console > Cognito > Manage User Pools for my app, and go to General settings > Users and groups, it doesn't find that user.

[image]

I've double checked that I'm using the correct Region and UserPoolClientID in app.settings, although can't find the UserPoolId in the management console, to double check that.

I'm also trying to register a user with the email address that I use for my aws account, if that makes a difference.

I'm not sure if there is an issue or if I'm doing something wrong. Any advice appreciated.

Comment: Check the response form Cognito that will have username and email. Also try searching by username. Could be your email is actually the username.

Comment: It doesn't find it by username either. I've set up my user pool so that users must sign in using their emails. I'm not sure what you mean by check the response form Cognito. If you're referring to the CognitoUser user object in the code above, that has a UserId and a Username property, which are both the email address I am searching for, but no Email property.

Comment: I have also tried to resend a confirmation code to the user using user.ResendConfirmationCodeAsync(), but it throws an exception saying "The operation was canceled." but there is no inner exception giving further information about why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't an error. The CognitoUserManager will always return a user, even if there isn't a user doesn't exist for that email. You need to check `user.Status != null` to see if the user actually exists.